# Python Pandas Extract text between a word and a symbol

Tags: python, pandas, regex, text-extraction

I am trying to extract text between a word and a symbol.

Here is the input table.

[image]

And my expected output is like this.

[image]

I do not want to have the word 'Team:' and '<>' in the output.

I tried something like this but it keeps the 'Team:' and '<>' in the output: data[new col]=data['Team'].str.extract(r'(Team:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+<>)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex captured group for `str.extract` method:

```
df['Team'].str.extract(r'^Team: ([^<>]+)')
```

---

- `[^<>]+` - matches any character except `<` and `>` chars

Comment: It works! Can you explain why the line could remove the word and symbol? Is it because of the ^?

Comment: it's because it extracts the captured group `(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular expression as this would account for countries with spaces and any N length.

```
import re

row_string = "Team: United States <>"
country_name = re.search(r'Team: (.*) <>', row_string).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you have the capture group around the whole match, which will be returned by `str.extract`

You could write it using the group only around the part that you want to keep:

```
df['Team'].str.extract(r'Team:\s([a-zA-Z\s]+)<>')
```

See the capture group values at this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uEkUDW/1).